# convert string array to integer array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$TaxIds=array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(2) "10" }
```

I need convert to this:

```
$TaxIds=array(2) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(10) }
```

simple way???

Comment: php is dynamic language. it will used the numeric value in string as number not string. `$TaxIds[0] + $TaxIds[1]` will output 15

Comment: $TaxIds[1] = (int)$TaxIds[1];

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$TaxIds = array_map(function($value) {
    return intval($value);
}, $TaxIds);
```

Comment: Since PHP 7.4 it's possible to write it with the arrow function syntax on one line:
`$TaxIds = array_map(fn($value) => intval($value), $TaxIds);`

Answer (score 24):

Simplified version of @george's answer would be:

```
$TaxIds = array_map('intval', $TaxIds);
```

More info at [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Although the question was asked a long time ago, it may be useful for someone

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution with [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$TaxIds=array_map(function ($v) {return (int)$v;},$TaxIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_walk($array, function(&$value, &$key) {
    settype($value, "integer");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could for loop it

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($TaxIds);$i++) {
    $TaxIds[$i] = (int) $TaxIds[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$TaxIds = ["5", "10"];
$TaxIds = array_map(function($elem) { return intval($elem); }, $TaxIds);
var_dump($TaxIds);
```

var_dump output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(10) }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions to this problem. Some of them have been already posted. You can use one other solution with foreach.

```
 foreach($TaxIds as &$taxId) {
    $taxId = intval($taxId);
 }
```

However, I don't think you need to cast it to integer. PHP will detect if you want to make numeric operation and cast it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
$TaxIds = array( "1" ,"5", "2" ,"10");
$TaxIds = array_map(function($arr) {
    return intval($arr);
}, $TaxIds);

var_dump($TaxIds);
```

Output

```
array (size=4)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 5
  2 => int 2
  3 => int 10
```

Answer (score -3):

You could try this:

```
$arr = array("1", "2");
$my = json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$dec = json_decode($my, true);
var_dump($dec);
```

Output: `array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) }`

Or, as others have suggested, you could use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$arr = array("1", "2");
$arr = array_map(function($value) {
    return intval($value);
}, $arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Output: `array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) }`

**Edit:**
Use the following if you are expecting actual string in the array:

```
$arr = array("1", "2");
$arr = array_map(function($value) {
       return is_numeric($value) ? intval($value) : $value
}, $arr);
```

Comment: It's likely because you're converting to JSON unnecessarily

Comment: The OP hasn't indicated that the array will contain strings that can't be parsed as integers, or what needs to be done with such values. If this *is* something the OP needs, it can be accomplished very easily by adjusting the function being passed to `array_map`. The use of JSON serialization is still unnecessary.

Comment: @Criesto `return is_numeric($value) ? intval($value) : $value`