# Return of function type array of Class

Tags: php, php-7

I found anything on the manual of `php` that i am needing:

```
function getSum(int ...$valores){

    return array_sum($valores);
}
```

here we are an array of $values been seend with in params.

Should be possible do something like:

```
function arrayOfStrings(int ...$values) : int ...values {

   $int = 0;

   foreach ($values as $value):
        $int += $value;
   endforeach;

    return $int;
}
```

My object is get it efect of out:

```
....: int ...values {}
```

**A typed array**

Comment: Are you trying to convert an array of integers to an array of strings? You can look into the function array_map, which lets you provide a callback function to apply against all elements of an array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435481/convert-string-array-to-integer-array-in-php

Comment: Sorry, y pated wrong code. already upadte on the question

Comment: may be this will help https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-type-hinting.html

Comment: no. there only one type. But i need of an array of types. For exemplo, Array (0=>Object1, 1=>Object2)...

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the answer is: no. PHP does not support a return type of "array of x". It only supports "array".

Comment: thank you. I am looking for a altenative only. But i already helpe me! Thank you!