# Remove double quote from from array of numbers php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

if we have array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"] how can we remove double quote and get new array = [1, 2, 3, 4] Using PHP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435481/convert-string-array-to-integer-array-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You could use **array_map()** followed by a casting from **string** to **int**.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php for more information.